# PST Timezone in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to find out a PST and EST timings in Ruby. I know finding the time in UTC.
What i found is there are no methods like PST & EST like we have UTC. Could some one help me how can i find PST timing in pure Ruby.

Here is what i have tried.

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Time.now
=> 2012-02-17 13:15:43 +0530

irb(main):002:0> b = Time.now.UTC

NoMethodError: undefined method `UTC' for 2012-02-17 13:15:52 +0530:Time

        from (irb):2

        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):003:0> b = Time.now.utc

=> 2012-02-17 07:45:56 UTC

irb(main):004:0> b = Time.now.pst

NoMethodError: undefined method `pst' for 2012-02-17 13:15:59 +0530:Time

        from (irb):4

        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'

irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ruby Time class is strangely limited in this regard. ActiveSupport includes a TimeWithZone class to fill this gap.

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html